# Filtering by Text in LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

Would it possible to filter text for a specific Tag?

I currently can filter Tags, but not specific text for a specific Tag.

**Reference**
(Tag Filtering: https://plus.google.com/106300001086744879268/posts/4hbonf2w51D)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

My LogCat can filter for LogTag, Log Message, PID, App Name, LogLevel.

But just when I update my SDK and ADT.

[]s
Bertan

Answer (score -1):

You can specify what you were looking for when you create a tag. You assign a name and you call that name.